# C++ reference variable from method

Tags: c++, reference

Does it make sense to do this:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    static Object getObject()
    {
        return Object("example")
    }
};

int main()
{
    const Object& myObject = SomeClass::getObject();

    // do something with myObject
}
```

or is this the same as just getting the Object like

```
const Object myObject = SomeClass::getObject();
```

?

Comment: Yes it is very close but not exactly the same, but if it makes sense or not depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The first one creates a reference to a temporary object. The `const` extends the life of that temporary object, so it's safe to do. The second creates a new object, likely through move semantics. You're probably not going to notice any difference between the two.

Comment: In the first code version, you should get compiler warning saying you get reference to temporary, don't you? This is because your `getObject` returns a newly created instance of type `Object`, not reference to an object being held elsewhere.

Comment: @mvidelgauz not really a reference extends lifetime of a temporary object, it is legal in this case.

Comment: @ChrisMM non const extends lifetime as well.

Comment: @Slava No they don't, and never have.

Comment: @Slava A non-const reference can't even be initialized with a temporary object to begin with, let alone extend the lifetime of the same. `Object& myObject = SomeClass::getObject();` wouldn't compile (except that MSVC accepts this code by default as a non-standard extension).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how about non const rvalue reference?

Comment: @molbdnilo as much as I know non const **rvalue** reference does since it was created.

Comment: `void main` is forbidden in c++. `main` is required to have the return type `int`.

Comment: I've removed my previous comments, I misunderstood the arguments being made here.

Comment: Useful topic, I just learned that `const` reference is the exception that extends lifetime of temporary. Makes sense :)

Comment: The const-reference might have been useful prior to C++17 to avoid copies of objects under some circumstances (copy elision was allowed, but not mandatory). Since then, I don't see much sense in it any more... Can anyone provide a counter example?

Answer (score 6):

From Herb Sutter's article on this topic, that can be found [here](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), both cases are correct:

> Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full
>   expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies
>   that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack
>   lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the
>   reference itself, and thus avoids what would otherwise be a common
>   dangling-reference error.

But if you remove `const` from case 1, it will not be OK.

Comment: without `const`, `Object&& myObject = SomeClass::getObject();` can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between the two when using NRVO.

The named return value optimisation can only work with local variable. Reference are not:

```
auto foo() -> Object
{
    const Object& myObject = SomeClass::getObject();
    return myObject; // no NRVO in this case
}

auto foo() -> Object
{
    const Object myObject = SomeClass::getObject();
    return myObject; // NRVO applies in this case
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/PRLUdP)